# Which external DAC to use with igrados headphones?

Tags: hardware, headphones

I have [igrados](http://www.grado.co.uk/grado-earphones/grado-igrado-sport-headphones.htm) for listening to music from my ipod-touch/nexus 4, and I'm considering buying an external DAC to improve the sound quality if possible.

Since igrados are very entry level and not very sensitive, I doubt using an external DAC will make any noticeable impact on the quality. But then I noticed that it uses the same sound drivers as [SR60s](http://www.grado.co.uk/grado-earphones/sr60i-headphones.htm) so there is a possibility of improvement.

Can anybody suggest a decent portable DAC for use?

Comment: Firstly, the signal leaving a headphone jack is already in the analog realm... Too late for a DAC.  Secondly, I realize you didn't choose to post your question on this site, but it is likely off-topic at AVP.  Please check out the [help section](http://avp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for insight as to why it may be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non-production equipment/use-cases